# PHPExcel How to de-select column or range after setting a style

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have this code in my action page, which centers text in a range in the J column of my active worksheet:

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$lastrow = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('J1:J'.$lastrow)
            ->getAlignment()
            ->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
```

This works fine, except that when I trigger the opening of MS Excel, and it opens the worksheet, the entire J column is highlighted. What I want is for the client to open the spreadsheet, but not have any columns or cells highlighted or selected.

Comment: I don't know to not select ANY cell, but you can use `setSelectedCells('A1')` on a sheet to select the top-left cell.

Comment: @kainaw That actually looks acceptable to me, thanks.

Comment: @kainaw You should submit this as an answer, so I can vote for it. =D
Exactly what I needed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know how to unselect all cells, but you can select the cell A1, which is the top left cell. That will give the appearance of "no cell selected" and will open the sheet scrolled to the top and left. The function call is simple:

```
setSelectedCells('A1')
```